# Complex circuit drawing in LaTeX

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

[image]

How do I draw this kind of circuit?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4size]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
   \node[and port, number inputs=1] (A) at (0, 0) {};
        \node at (A) [ocirc] {};
        \node[left] at (A.in 1) {\(x\)};
        \node[left] at (A.in 2) {\(y\)};
        
        \node[and port, number inputs=1] (B) at (0,4) {};
        \node[left] at (B.in 2) {\(y\)};
        
        
        \draw (A.out) -- ++ (2,0) -- ++ (0,0.28) -- ++ (0.5,0) (B.left);
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This is incomplete coding. I tried as far I could. I am a beginner in `circuitikz`. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here's one way to do it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        % Gates
        \node[and port] (and1) at (0, 0) {};
        \node[and port] (and2) at (0, -2) {};
        \node[not port, scale=0.5] (not) at ($(and2.in 2) - (2, 0)$) {};
        \node[or port] (or) at (4, -1) {};
        
        % Circuit inputs
        \node (in1) at ($(and1.in 1) - (3, 0)$) {};
        \node (in2) at ($(and1.in 2) - (3, 0)$) {};
        \node (in3) at ($(and2.in 1) - (3, 0)$) {};
        \node (in4) at ($(and2.in 2) - (3, 0)$) {};
        
        % Input wires
        \draw (in1) -- (and1.in 1);
        \draw (in2) -- (and1.in 2);
        \draw (in3) -- (and2.in 1);
        \draw (in4) -- (not.in);
        \draw (not.out) -- (and2.in 2) node[midway, below] {\(z'\)};
        
        % Input labels
        \node at (in1) {\(x\)};
        \node at (in2) {\(y\)};
        \node at (in3) {\(y\)};
        \node at (in4) {\(z\)};
        
        % Output wires from first round of gates
        \draw (and1.out) -- ++ (1, 0) |- (or.in 1) node[midway, above right] {\(xy\)};
        \draw (and2.out) -- ++ (1, 0) |- (or.in 2) node[midway, below right] {\(yz'\)};
        
        % Final output
        \draw (or.out) -- ++ (1, 0) node[right] {\(xy + yz'\)};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This makes use of `|-` which, along with `-|` allow you to project out a single coordinate. That is `(A |- B)` has the same `x` coordinate as the node `(A)` and the same `y` coordinate as the node `(B)`.
Similarly `(A -| B)` has the same `x` coordinate as `(B)` and the same `y` coordinate as `(A)`.

Comment: I think that you can shorten your code by replacing `\draw (and1.out) -- ($(and1.out) + (1, 0)$) -- ($(and1.out) + (1, 0)$)` by `\draw (and1.out) --++ (1, 0)`, with no need to use the `calc` library here.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'll change it as I think that is nicer. I just default to the `calc` library out of habit

Comment: Still, I don't understand why you let a redundancy. `\draw (and1.out) -- ++ (1, 0) -- (and1.out) ++ (1, 0)` means that you go back and forth. Why wouldn't you just use `\draw (and1.out) -- ++ (1, 0)`? It's no big deal, but it keeps me intrigued.

Comment: You are correct again, I've changed it